# Accessing logged user from a filter

Tags: java, spring, filter, spring-security

I have a Spring 3 application with Spring Security. I need to do some proccessing in almost all the urls of my application. The proccesing is different depending on the user which is logged-in. I had though of doing it by using a Spring filter but I cannot access

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()
```

in the filter because SecurityContextHolder is still null.

What is the best way to do this?

thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636172/does-acegi-spring-security-support-getuserprincipal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the security context, your filter should be behind the Spring Security filter, i.e. its `<filter-mapping>` should be placed after the Spring Security's one.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using spring, you can do it inside ["interceptor"](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping). It spring's alternative to filters, and it have access to security context.